# What are some good ways to implement a read line or a sleep timer in Rust

Tags: rust, command-line-interface, rust-cargo

I've finished my CLI but it exits too quickly for people to use it, Anyone know how would I go towards implementing code in my main.rs without breaking the compiler lol.
I was thinking of maybe a for loop that prints , read and execute and then start again. Or maybe a read line function so it stays up long enough to output the display.

Where would you guys implement that ? Thanks!

```
      use structopt::StructOpt;
      mod cli;
      mod task;



  use cli::{Action::*, CommandLineArgs};
  use task::Task;

     fn main() {
 // Get the command-line arguments.
   let CommandLineArgs {
    action,
    todo_file,
 } = CommandLineArgs::from_args();

  // Unpack the todo file.
 let todo_file = todo_file.expect("Failed to find todo file");

// Perform the action.
   match action {
    Add { text } => task::add_task(todo_file, 
   Task::new(text)),
    List => task::list_tasks(todo_file), 
    Done { position } => 
 task::complete_task(todo_file, position),

    

   }  
   .expect("Failed to perform action")

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the example, it seems you're getting the arguments from the command line.  If you instead wanted the program to wait for a user to enter some text, interpret that text as a command and run it, and then wait for input again, until the user exits the program, then you'll probably want https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdin.html or possibly a higher level crate such as https://docs.rs/rustyline/8.0.0/rustyline/

If you were using stdin directly, you can call `io::stdin().read_line()` which will wait until the user has entered a line of text and pressed enter before the function will return.  You can then parse that string to get the action to perform.  The input/parsing/action code can be surrounded in a `loop {}` and one of the actions can be an exit command that will exit the loop.

Comment: Awesome response! That's exactly what I'm trying to do I'm planning to use stdin().read_line(&mut string)  or a loop but I'm having problems nesting it within my main.rs it seems to give problems with the modules. I'll definitely read the docs